# Using CAST or CONVERT inside a view MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi Having a syntax issue - at least I think it is. I want a default date as part of a case statement inside a materialised view (MS SQL 2008 +):

```
, CASE 
    WHEN WithFirstDate = 0 THEN CONVERT(DATE,'1900-JAN-1', 101)
    WHEN WithFirstDate = 1 THEN
        Start1
    ELSE --WithFirstDate = 2 
        Start2
    END ValidDate
```

I'm getting the following error:
view uses an implicit conversion from string to datetime or smalldatetime. Use an explicit CONVERT with a deterministic style value

I'd like to have a solution that works irrespective of localization (i.e US style dates, Japanese style dates and the rest of the world)

Thanks

Comment: What are the sql data types of Start1, Start2, and ValidDate?

Comment: ValidDate is just an alias, not a column. But yes, the data types of the other two columns is important to know.

Comment: You seem to keep doing somewhat random edit rollbacks. Please pick a version you like and stick with it.

Comment: Both Start1 and Start2 are computed DATE type columns

Comment: It would seem that you cant use a case statement inside a materialised view to choose between 2 columns.

Comment: Re random rollbacks - the question was edited by numerous people (8) who made grammatical and styling corrections which IMHO added nothing to the Bards language. I just rolled them all back. If a moderator want to look into this I'm happy.

Comment: The computed columns seem to be causing the problem but its not a date type issue

Answer (score 5):

Instead of:

```
CONVERT(DATE,'1900-JAN-1', 101)
```

Just do:

```
CONVERT(DATE,'1900-01-01')
```

However the issue may be with the other two columns, `Start1` and `Start2`. I am guessing these are not `DATE` columns.

Comment: +1 to it. The problem seems to be that case returns a datetime value when 0 and a no datetime otherwise.

Comment: Both Start1 and Start2 are computed columns with DATE type

Comment: Did you try DATETIME instead of DATE? I think there is some confusion here about the difference between the two. Also can you add to the question the code for the view and the schema for the underlying tables please? Pulling teeth is tiresome.

Answer (score 1):

The 101 code you are passing the CONVERT function does not match your format. Check the following link to find the correct code:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Look at the table, 100 doesn't match '1900-JAN-1' either. Take Aaron's advice and drop the code altogether if it isn't working for you: CONVERT(DATE,'1900-01-01')

Answer (score 0):

Ok well this forum has gone downhill IMHO, first my post get endless edited for grammar which doesn't change the meaning, then it gets voted down presumably because it was "to difficult" to answer. https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand was on the right lines. Thanks Aaron. The problem was a computed column in one of the referenced tables was non deterministic. This error only resolved in a flag when the materialising clustered index was being created on the view. I'd post a link to the full answer but not allowed. Shame I cant recover all my old badges and points from a couple of years ago. Full answer here http://tinyurl.com/knor8qk